# How do I get XHR/Ajax resource timing data from window.performance?

Tags: performance, firefox, selenium, xmlhttprequest, timing

When I open the Firefox "network" tab in the developer tools, I'm able to see the timing data from all the requests my page is making, including application/json (XHR) calls. I want to be able to get this timing information programmatically.

In Selenium, I let my page load fully and then ask the `window.performance.getEntries()` method for all of the resources. It gives me back a ton, including CSS, javascript, etc, but I don't see the calls to our RESTful services that show up in the Firefox window as "json" requests.

Since Firefox shows them in its Network tab in the developer tools, is a way for me to get them programatically? Our app is an angular app that is not using iframes.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my issue after a day of googling and trying different things. Thanks to [this article](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2014/08/21/resource-timing-practical-tips/) I discovered that I needed to add `Timing-Allow-Origin: *` to the response header of all the services.

Once I did that, the timing information started to appear. It's apparently because the services are hosted at a different domain than my client. I don't understand the ramifications of leaving that header in there so I'll make sure it doesn't get deployed to production.